# R: Quickest way to summarize number of observations for multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr, summary

I am sure this is a super simple thing, but I cannot find a really quick and easy solution.

I have patient data with a lot of columns in a format like this:

```
patID   disease   category ...
1       1          A
2       0          B
3       1          C
4       1          B
```

How can I quickly produce a summary table, which includes the number of observations for each column/variable in the dataframe? The result should be something like this:

```
VARIABLE     Number of rows
disease:1    3
disease:0    1
category:A   1
category:B   2
category:C   1
...
```

I know I can do this for a single variable by just using table(data$column). But how can I produce something similar for all columns in a dataframe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```
gather(data, variable, value, -patID) %>%
  count(variable, value)
```

(Thanks @Frank for reminding me about `tally` and `count`.)

Comment: `summarise(n())` has a shortcut: `tally`. There's also `count` that would avoid the need for the `group_by` (Sorry for the comment edit; just remembered the latter after looking at the docs)